# Do American say "fugly"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

[Cambridge  dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fugly)

> fugly adjective mainly UK very informal UK  /ˈfʌɡ.li/ US  /ˈfʌɡ.li/
> Add to word list  very ugly: Oh, that girl is fugly!

It seems this is a slang from UK

**Do American people say it?**

Comment: from the UK,  I've never heard it... but I'd assume it means fucking ugly,  and should only be used in contexts in which you would use fuck  (ie, please don't teach it to your daughter!)

Comment: @JamesK - I've seen it in mainly US casual sources. Interestingly, the Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang (2010) gives the source as 'Australian military' with a date of 1970. I can only link to the [summary of the entry](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780199543700.001.0001/acref-9780199543700-e-1656), as I do not have an account to view the online dictionary.

Comment: I think the word had its origins in the high school locker room

Comment: @TimR - and probably in the male one (Do girls have locker rooms?).

Comment: Odd that it says "mainly UK." Not being UK I guess I wouldn't know, but I've heard it plenty in the US. (Well, maybe not since high school, but plenty then.) Etymonline attests to James's etymological guess, but says "since 1995," which pretty well dates to my high school days, and has risen since.

Comment: @AndyBonner - Oxford says 'mainly UK', and Cambridge blames it on the Aussies!

Comment: It doesn't seem confined to people; I've seen it used casually about a suit of clothes, curtains, a dress, and Las Vegas in the 1970s.

Comment: I'm British and have never used that word in my life, and never heard anybody use it.  The only way I know the word is because there is a website (American run) called fugly.com - which was popular for a while.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The OED blames it on the Aussies and gives the first citation "a1970

    Fugly, an extremely ugly woman. A blending of ‘fucking’ and ‘ugly’ to describe the woman.

in R. J. Rayward, More than Mere Bravo (1989) 122".  After googling it, the book seems to be about slang in the Australian military from 1930 -1950, at Duntroon Military College, Canberra, in Australia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, I say it and many people I know say it.  I heard it more in the Midwest (where I used to live) than the Pacific Northwest (where I live now), and it does seem to be trending less common over time, but definitely American slang as well - anyone hearing it in America would understand the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as an American who spent most of his life in Michigan ... I don't recall ever hearing the word.

Of course that's anecdotal evidence. It might be very common in certain circles, just not in the circles that I move in. Slang is notoriously hard to pin down because it often comes and goes very quickly. A word used by every high school student today may be completely forgotten in 5 years. There are words commonly used by, say, video gamers, that are totally unknown by football players. Etc.

But for what it's worth, I'm an American and I never heard the word until I read this post.